# Removing moving images in android when tapped

Tags: android, image, class

I am making an android game that has a set of moving images on a screen that i display with a class and a surfaceview i think it was. I have added a function to a doDraw() method, that checks the location of a parachuter and removes them if there are at the bottom of the screen, or if they have a boolean "setTouched" set to true. But i need something in the onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) method that set's the boolean of a parachuter to setTouched(true); once a parachuter is touched. How can i do this? Please help me and thanks so much in advance! This is the code that i am using:

Main game code that includes onTouchEvent and such:

```
package com.mysoftwaremobileapps.ParachuteHunter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExampleView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
class ExampleThread extends Thread
{
    private ArrayList<Parachuter> parachuters;
    private Bitmap parachuter;
    private Paint black;

    private boolean running;

    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Context mContext;
    private Context mContext1;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Handler mHandler1;
    private GameScreenActivity mActivity;

    private long frameRate;
    private boolean loading;
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public MediaPlayer mp1;
    public int parachuterIndexToResetAndDelete;
    public int canvasGetWidth;
    public int livesLeftValue;

    public ExampleThread(SurfaceHolder sHolder, Context context, Handler handler)
    {
        mSurfaceHolder = sHolder;
        mHandler = handler;
        mHandler1 = handler;
        mContext = context;
        mActivity = (GameScreenActivity) context;

        parachuters = new ArrayList<Parachuter>();
        parachuter = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.parachuteman);
        black = new Paint();
        black.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        black.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        running = true;

        // This equates to 26 frames per second.
        frameRate = (long) (1000 / 26);
        loading = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            Canvas c = null;
            try
            {
                c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder)
                {
                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    doDraw(c);
                    long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

                    if (diff < frameRate)
                        Thread.sleep(frameRate - diff);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                if (c != null)
                {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void doDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), black);
        canvasGetWidth = canvas.getWidth();

        //Draw
        for (int i = 0; i < parachuters.size(); i++)
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(parachuter, parachuters.get(i).getX(), parachuters.get(i).getY(), null);
            parachuters.get(i).tick();
        }

        //Remove
        for (int i = 0; i < parachuters.size(); i++)
        {
        if (parachuters.get(i).getY() > canvas.getHeight()) {
            parachuters.remove(i);
            onPlaySound();
            checkLivesLeftValue();
        }
    }
    }


    private void checkLivesLeftValue() {
        Log.d("checkLivesLeftValue", "lives = " + livesLeftValue);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (livesLeftValue == 3) {
            //Message to display: "You lost!
            Log.d("checkLivesLeftValue", "calling onMethod now");
            onMethod();
        }
        else {
            livesLeftValue = livesLeftValue + 1;
            Log.d("checkLivesLeftValue", "increased lives to " + livesLeftValue);
        }
    }
    public void onMethod() {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You lost!", 15).show();
                livesLeftValue = 0;
                //Tell the user that he lost:
                android.content.Context ctx = mContext;
                Intent i = new Intent(ctx, playerLostMessageActivity.class);  
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                ctx.startActivity(i);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onPlaySound()
    {
        try {
        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.bombsound);
        mp1.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mp1.release();
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            return false;
        float x1 = event.getX();
        float y1 = event.getY();


        return true;
    }

    public void initiateDrawParachuters()
    {
        drawParachutersGroup1();
    }
    public void drawParachutersGroup1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Parachuter group nr. 1

        //Parachuter nr. 2
        x = 75;
        y = 77;

        Parachuter p1 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p1);
        //Parachuter nr.1
        x = 14;
        y = 28;

        Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p);

        //Parachuter nr. 3
        x = 87;
        y = 94;

        Parachuter p3 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p3);

        //Parachuter nr. 3
        x = 85;
        y = 80;

        Parachuter p2 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p2);

        //Parachuter nr. 5
        x = 67;
        y = 163;

        Parachuter p5 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p5);

        x = 217;
        y = 118;

        Parachuter p4 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p4);

        //Parachuter nr. 7
        x = 297;
        y = 247;

        Parachuter p7 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p7);

        //Parachuter nr. 6
        x = 19;
        y = 57;

        Parachuter p6 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p6);
    }

    public void drawParachutersGroup2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Parachuter group nr. 2

        //Parachuter nr. 5
        x = 57;
        y = 166;

        Parachuter p5 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p5);

        x = 283;
        y = 123;

        Parachuter p4 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p4);

        //Parachuter nr. 7
        x = 99;
        y = 213;

        Parachuter p7 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p7);

        //Parachuter nr. 6
        x = 231;
        y = 121;

        Parachuter p6 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p6);
    }

    public void drawParachutersGroup3() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Parachuter group nr. 3

        //Parachuter nr. 2
        x = 33;
        y = 115;

        Parachuter p1 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p1);
        //Parachuter nr.1
        x = 277;
        y = 183;

        Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p);

        //Parachuter nr. 3
        x = 127;
        y = 280;

        Parachuter p3 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p3);

        //Parachuter nr. 3
        x = 84;
        y = 80;

        Parachuter p2 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p2);

        //Parachuter nr. 5
        x = 67;
        y = 112;

        Parachuter p5 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p5);

        x = 260;
        y = 89;

        Parachuter p4 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p4);

        //Parachuter nr. 7
        x = 283;
        y = 113;

        Parachuter p7 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p7);

        //Parachuter nr. 6
        x = 295;
        y = 25;

        Parachuter p6 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p6);
    }

    public void drawParachutersGroup4() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Parachuter group nr. 1

        //Parachuter nr. 2
        x = 75;
        y = 166;

        Parachuter p1 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p1);
        //Parachuter nr.1
        x = 118;
        y = 94;

        Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p);

        //Parachuter nr. 3
        x = 38;
        y = 55;

        Parachuter p3 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p3);

        //Parachuter nr. 3
        x = 22;
        y = 18;

        Parachuter p2 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p2);

        //Parachuter nr. 5
        x = 67;
        y = 119;

        Parachuter p5 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p5);

        x = 217;
        y = 113;

        Parachuter p4 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p4);

        //Parachuter nr. 7
        x = 345;
        y = 234;

        Parachuter p7 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p7);

        //Parachuter nr. 6
        x = 346;
        y = 44;

        Parachuter p6 = new Parachuter(x, y);
        parachuters.add(p6);
    }

    public void drawParachuters()
    {
            Parachuter p = new Parachuter(x, y);
            parachuters.add(p);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "x=" + x + " y=" + y, 15).show();
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean bRun)
    {
        running = bRun;
    }

    public boolean getRunning()
    {
        return running;
    }
}

/** Handle to the application context, used to e.g. fetch Drawables. */
private Context mContext;

/** Pointer to the text view to display "Paused.." etc. */
private TextView mStatusText;

/** The thread that actually draws the animation */
private ExampleThread eThread;

public ExampleView(Context context)
{
    super(context);

    // register our interest in hearing about changes to our surface
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);

    // create thread only; it's started in surfaceCreated()
    eThread = new ExampleThread(holder, context, new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message m)
        {
           // mStatusText.setVisibility(m.getData().getInt("viz"));
           // mStatusText.setText(m.getData().getString("text"));
        }
    });

    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    return eThread.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public ExampleThread getThread()
{
    return eThread;
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    if (eThread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED)
    {
        eThread = new ExampleThread(getHolder(), getContext(), getHandler());
        eThread.start();
    }
    else
    {
        eThread.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    boolean retry = true;
    eThread.setRunning(false);

    while (retry)
    {
        try
        {
            eThread.join();
            retry = false;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }
    }
}
}
```

Custom image class:

```
package com.mysoftwaremobileapps.ParachuteHunter;

public class Parachuter
{
float posX;
float posY;
float rate;
private boolean touched;

public Parachuter(float x, float y)
{
    posX = x;
    posY = y;
    rate = 5;
}

public void tick()
{
    posY += rate;
}

public float getX()
{
    return posX;
}

public float getY()
{
    return posY;
}
public boolean isTouched() {
    return touched;
}

public void setTouched(boolean touched) {
    this.touched = touched;
}
}
```

Comment: You know, you should put those parachuter group values in lists and iterate through them instead of writing them all out individually. It'll cut down on your code and also make it easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through all parachuters in onTouchEvent, and for each parachuter check if the touch coordinates are inside the parachuter.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        return false;
    float x1 = event.getX();
    float y1 = event.getY();

    for (Parachuter p: parachuters) {
        if (x1 > p.getX() && x1 < p.getX() + parachuter.getWidth() && y1 > p.getY() && y1 < p.getY() + parachuter.getHeight()) {
            p.setTouched(true);
        }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Do i have do add a .getWidth() in the parachuter class? It says that i have to do that

Comment: Well, yes, you should know the width and height of your image in order to find out if it was pressed.

Comment: Aaaaa, could you post me some code that i could add to the parachuter class. And i'll also try myself

Comment: You can take width and height from the bitmap, I didn't mention that your bitmap is also named parachuter, I edited the answer, now it should work.

Comment: I tried it, but get this message: The method setTouched(boolean) is undefined for the type Bitmap. Shouldn't the .setTouched(boolean) be used for the parachuter and not the bitmap???

Comment: Please help me with this problem, i have tried myself without success.(The above comment)

Comment: I have done everything now, and it seems to work 50/50. Some parachuters dissapear but some stays, really weird. Do you know what i can do?